# Cant install anything with current iptables rules. What am I missing?

Tags: networking, software-center, iptables, firewall

Heres my iptables rules below. I am trying to block everything except whats needed. I am not able to apt-get install with these rules. What am I missing?

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: delete the protocol specification in your output rules, You need to also allow tcp protocol. I assume you are using a static IP address, otherwise you need to allow ports 67 and 68 for DHCP.

Comment: You block the connections from outside of your network (the incoming) not the outgoing ones. That is unless you want your machine not functioning like now. Then it would be nice to know what you seek to accomplish. Do you have servers on this machine, if so why are you seeking to block them from being contacted? The whole point of having a server is for it to serve, unless only for the use of local network services.